# Remove unit number clause from street address string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, street-address

I'm using R for geocoding. Some of my street addresses include unit numbers and I need to remove those before geocoding, but I'm not very good at regex commands. How could I transform addresses like these:

10 Fake St, Unit #5, New York, NY 10001
10 Fake St, Units #5,6,7, New York, NY 10001

into this:

10 Fake St, New York, NY 10001

Thanks!

Comment: `sub("^((?:[^,]*,){2}).*,", "\\1", x)`

Comment: *how do I get rid of everything between the first comma and the last comma?* - Why? I think you want to remove all between the 2nd and last comma. See the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

just replace `\s+Units? \S+` with `""`

`\s+` is one or more spaces

`Units?` matches Unit or Units followed by a space

`\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters (so it will match until the next space)

Comment: Thanks! But what some of the addresses don't have the word "units"? Basically how do I get rid of everything between the first comma and the last comma?

Comment: `.*?,(.*),.*` will do that, but I don't recommend using such an open ended pattern. You could end up with more than you're looking for. [You can see it here](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/7)

Comment: You're right that doesn't work well. What about everything between the first comma and the substring "New York,"?

Comment: [Just add in the new york part `.*?,(.*) New York,.*`](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/10) Then again, this only works if it contains "New York". I suggest you find some sort of pattern that can be reproduced for the data that you don't want.

Comment: If it always contains "#" when referring to units, you could do `([\s\w]+#\S+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/15)

Answer (score 0):

We look for Unit with an optional appended s (`Units?`) and then a # followed by numbers and a comma an infinite number of times (`#(\d+,)+`). The one extra change is to add an optional space after the comma to fix formatting (`#(\d+, ?)+`).

`/Units? #(\d+, ?)+/g`

```js
const str = `10 Fake St, Unit #5, New York, NY 10001
10 Fake St, Units #5,6,7, New York, NY 10001`;

console.log(str.replace(/Units? #(\d+, ?)+/g, ""));
```